# Add elements to a plot in Shiny after already rendered

Tags: shiny

After rendering a plot in the app I am working on I would like the option to add ablines, and for these to remain part of the plot object, i.e. if the x axis changes it remains. I know what I could redefine the plotted object, but as there are several different options to the plot this method won't work as I will have countless different plot calls and I won't be able to track all of them if I need to change something.
Is there something similar to the dlypr %>% that can be used with plots in shiny, or anything which will have the same affect?

I have tried to run in separately, as shown in the code below. This does not add a line to the plot however.

```r
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

x <- faithful[, 2] 
x2 = x

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for cut
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("lines",
                   "Vertical Line",
                   min = 1,
                   value = 60),
      actionButton("add", "Add?"),
      numericInput("xlimL", "Lower x", value=0),
      numericInput("xlimU", "Upper x", value=50)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactiveValues(x2 = x2)

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(data$x2, xlim = c(input$xlimL, input$xlimU))
  })

  observeEvent(input$add,{
    abline(v = input$lines)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am after a plot with an abline added, and when I change the x limits it stays with the plot, and to do this without numerous renderPlot calls.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do this by making the data a `reactiveValue`, and adding `lines = NULL` this can be done but having the server section being the following:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactiveValues(x2 = x2, lines = NULL)

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(data$x2, xlim = c(input$xlimL, input$xlimU))
    abline(v =  data$lines)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add,{
    data$lines = c(data$lines, input$lines)
  })
}
```